# Eclipse is saying that 'MyFirstListener' is undefined, yet i have defined it in another class I am calling on, I am not sure what is wrong

Tags: java, plugins

I am trying to create my first plugin for Minecraft, however, I keep getting the errors: The constructor MyFirstListener(Main) is undefined
and:  The method registerEvents(Listener, Plugin) in the type 
PluginManager is 
not applicable for the arguments (MyFirstListener, Main)
I was not sure where to put this as I am fairly new to coding java and plugins, so I just put it here.

```
//first class    
package com.courbie.helloworld;

import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginManager;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin{

    @EventHandler
    public void onEnable() {

        getLogger().info("Hey Courbie, have a good day!");
        PluginManager pm = getServer().getPluginManager();
        MyFirstListener listener = new MyFirstListener();
        pm.registerEvents(listener, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        getLogger().info("MyPlugin has been disabled.");
    }

}

//Second class
package com.courbie.helloworld;

import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;

public class MyFirstListener implements Listener{

    //Constructor
    public void FirstListener (final Main Plugin) {

    }

    //EventHandler
    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event) {

        event.getPlayer().sendMessage("Hello! How are you today Courbie?");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor is incorrect. First of all a constructor should not have a return type, second of all it should be named the same as the class. Change to:

```
//Constructor
public MyFirstListener (final Main plugin) {
```

There is also a problem with the way you call this constructor. You write:

```
MyFirstListener listener = new MyFirstListener();
```

But your constructor takes an argument of type `Main`. You can either remove the argument from your constructor:

```
//Constructor
public MyFirstListener () {
```

Or you can pass an argument of type `Main`:

```
MyFirstListener listener = new MyFirstListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second class: 
    //Constructor
    public void FirstListener (final Main Plugin) {

```
} is not a valid constructor.
```

That is why are getting an error for MyFirstListener(Main) is not defined.
Please refer:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Hope this helps.